# Sum of squares squared in an arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progression, sums-of-squares

Let $r(n)$ be the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of two squares and $(a,q)=1$.
What is known about
$$
\sum_{n \le x,n \equiv a (\text{mod} \, q)} r(n)^2 \quad?
$$

I am looking for uniform results in $a,q$. For sum of $r(n)$ in an arithmetic progression, the result is due to Smith and has some further refinements, however, for $r(n)^2$ I fail to find a reference.

Comment: I doubt this very particular sum is in the literature. But it would be easy to study it. Since you can connect $r(n)$ to $(1\star \chi_4)(n)$, you should study the latter on average over primes. In particular, $\sum_{p\leq x } (1\star \chi_4)(p)^2\sim 2 \pi(x)$ so the asymptotic ought to be of the form $ \phi(q)^{-1}  x (\log x )^2+c'(a,q) x+O(q^M x^{1-\epsilon})$ with absolute implied constants and where $M,\epsilon$ are positive absolute constants. One can surely prove this estimate by Perron integration. Not sure if this estimate is sufficient for your application though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I will check if it suffices!

Comment: @Dr.Pi I think you meant $x \log x$ instead of $x (\log x)^2$.

Comment: yes indeed, sorry! i will edit it.